# Группировка запроса mysql по условию

Tags: php, mysql

Добра всем.
В таблицу `table_name` записывается каждые 15 минут следующие данные:
`id` (AUTOINCREMENT), `date` (в Unix), `max` - максимальное число чего-то на данный момент времени.
Задача состоит в том, что мне нужно создать график значений `max` за неделю, чтобы каждый пункт в графике был средним количеством `max` за определенный день

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо использовать `SELECT AVG(max_field) ... GROUP BY DATE(date_field)`:

```
SELECT
  DATE(`date`) AS date_field,
  AVG(max_value) AS avg_value
FROM table_name

WHERE `date` >= '2014-01-01' AND `date` < '2014-01-08'

GROUP BY date_field
```

[ПРИМЕР](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46c08/2)

Вот [ПРИМЕР](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/826ab/3) с преобразованием даты из одного формата в другой.

Comment: @urichalex, с чего это? Любую дату можно отформатировать так, как надо. Сейчас пример отредактирую

Comment: Не вышло...
Таблица такая:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aza_stat` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `max` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Запрос:

SELECT DATE(  `date` ) AS date_field, AVG(  `max` ) AS avg_value
FROM aza_stat
WHERE  `date` >=  '2015-02-10'
AND  `date` <  '2015-02-12'
GROUP BY date_field

Возвращает 0 строк. Если убрать группировку, возвращает date_field NULL и avg_value NULL

Comment: @urichalex, обновил ответ - посмотрите, как сделал преобразование дат.

И вопрос: а зачем хранить в таком виде? Может быть, дату хранить как дату? MySQL сам неплохо справляется с типом данных для хранения (он же не строкой дату хранит)), можно же при вставке преобразовывать дату в требуемый вид.

Почитайте [доки по дате](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Comment: Ну вот такая вот мне таблица досталась, и, если переделывать на троку дату, то много чего переписывать придется.
Сейчас сделал заппрос вот так:

SELECT DATE( DATE ) AS date_field, AVG( max ) AS avg_value
FROM aza_stat
WHERE DATE >=  '1422738000'
AND DATE <  '1423688400'
GROUP BY DATE( date_field )

Теперь она возвращает одну строку, где date_field NULL и avg_value 18.2551

Comment: Вы посмотрите мой второй пример, там же написано: дату в unix мы преобразуем к дате mysql через `FROM_UNIXTIME`, т.е. запрос начинается так:

    SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`DATE`)) AS date_field...

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Спасибо огромное =)